# SWT ProgressMonitorDialog vs Job

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface, rcp

I would like to use a progress monitor that is non-modal and can be shrunk to the bottom-right of the status bar.

As far as I can tell from testing, ProgressMonitorDialog correctly displays the progress bar to the user, and can be made modal using the following code below.  However there are no hooks to shrink it to the bottom-right of the status bar. The code kind of looks like this:

```
try {
    ProgressMonitorDialog pmd = new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell){
        @Override
        protected void setShellStyle(int newShellStyle) {           
            super.setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS| 
                SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
            setBlockOnOpen(false);
        }  
    };
    pmd.run(true, true, new MyOperation());
} catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
    MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error", e.getMessage());
} catch (final InterruptedException e) {
    MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Cancelled", e.getMessage());
}

class MyOperation implements IRunnableWithProgress {
    @Override
    public void run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws 
      InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        monitor.beginTask("start task", 10);

        // time consuming work here
        doExpensiveWork(monitor);

        monitor.done();
    }
```

When I test with Job, the jobs run as expected but I get no visual feedback.
My code is similar to this:

```
final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.SMOOTH);
progressBar.setBounds(100, 10, 200, 20);

// Setting the progress monitor
final IJobManager manager = Job.getJobManager();

final IProgressMonitor p = new IProgressMonitor() {

    @Override
    public void worked(final int work) {
        sync.syncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setSelection(progressBar.getSelection() + work);
        }
    });
    //....
}

Job job = new Job("test") {

    @Override
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("start task", 10);

        // time consuming work here
        doExpensiveWork(monitor);
        // sync with UI
        syncWithUI();

        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }

};
job.setUser(true);
job.schedule();
```

What am I missing to be able to get a version of the ProgressMonitorDialog that can shrink to the bottom-right of the status bar when the user minimizes the tab?

Comment: Is your code running in the Eclipse Workbench (i.e. within a plug-in)?

Comment: With `setUser(true)` the job should show a progress dialog, but only if the job runs for more than a few seconds.

Comment: I am running it in an RCP4 application.  setUser is set to true, but I do not see any visual feedback.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I should also mention the job can run for minutes, so I would expect to see a popup by then

Answer (score 0):

No idea how about ProgressDialog, but show progress while using jobs, you have to set

```
IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
setShowProgressIndicator(true);
```

in the 
*org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen()*