# Eclipse RCP Progress Monitor not showing anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application that's using ProgressMonitors to provide continuous feedback to the user. All worked fine since a few days ago when suddenly **all** ProgressMonitors used in the application failed to show up.

```
IProgressMonitor monitor = Job.getJobManager().createProgressGroup()
Job jobMain = new Job("Initializing ...") {
    @Override 
    protected IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("doing stuff", 100); 
        // DO STUFF  
        return Status.OK_STATUS; 
    }
}; 
jobMain.setUser(true); 
jobMain.setProgressGroup(monitor, 100); 
jobMain.schedule();
```

Is this an Eclipse issue? Has anyone ever had that problem that **no** Progress Dialogs showed anymore?

Comment: What class do you get in `monitor`? If things are not set up properly `createProgressGroup` can return `NullProgressMonitor`.

Comment: What do you mean by "what class"? I don't think that this is a code related issue as it worked perfectly until a few days ago.

Comment: I mean what is `monitor` an instance of? If things are set up properly it should be an instance of `org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.GroupInfo`.

Comment: Job.getJobManager().createProgressGroup() returns an instance of type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor

Comment: That is the interface that it returns, I want you to do some debugging and see what the actual class implementing that interface is being returned. That might be a simple as just printing out the value of `monitor.getClass().getName()`

Answer (score 0):

We had the same thing occur in our RCP application during P2 updates once we moved to 2020-09 (we were on a much older platform). What ended up solving the problem for us was https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440793/13170238

I.E. setting :

```
IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
configurer.setShowProgressIndicator(true);
```

in the *org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen()*